# How to count time from current reference time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, ksh

I need to build simple ksh/bash scrip or whatever on Linux t that know to count time from reference time

When I type the date command as the following:

```
   date

   Wed Jul 17 18:13:27 IDT 2013
```

or

```
   [root@linux /var/tmp]# current_time=` date `
   [root@linux /var/tmp]# echo $current_time

                          Wed Jul 17 18:21:51 IDT 2013
```

So I get here the current date .

What I need is to count for example 10 min from the current date ,

so after 10 min I will print the message

```
     echo “sorry 10 min was ended“
```

how to count time from the reference time ?

Comment: `sleep 10 && echo "hi"` will display "hi" after 10 seconds, for example.

Comment: I not want to sleep , in the code I need perfrom some other actions , I need to start to count from the reference time only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `date +%s` to get Unix time - the number of seconds since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970 - and then use arithmetic expansion:

```
current_time=$(date +%s)
elapsed_time=$(( $(date +%s) - $current_time ))
```

`$elapsed_time` is then the number of seconds since `$current_time`. You can then check if `$elapsed_time > 600` in your loop.

**Edit:** For completeness:

```
if [[ $elapsed_time > 600 ]]; then
   echo "sorry 10 min was ended"
fi
```

This should work in both bash and ksh.

Answer (score 4):

`bash` has something like a built-in timer. The parameter `$SECONDS` is updated continuously with the number of seconds elapsed since the shell was started. You can assign to this variable, in which case its value is essentially incremented each second.

Some examples:

```
$ SECONDS=0
$ sleep 10
$ echo $SECONDS
10

$ SECONDS=0
$ while (( SECONDS < 600 )); do
>  sleep 10
> done
```